# Script-generated files cannot be found as a project resource

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bash, shell

So, I have a `shell script` which generates two `JSON` files. The script is run as a '`build Phase`' in `Xcode`. I'm expecting to have programmatic access to these generated files, but in code they cannot be found.

Here is the code which generates the files (I don't specify any paths - the `Script` is located in the root of my project):

```
echo $booksJSON >> defaultBooks.json
echo $dateJSON >> defaultBooksDate.json`
```

I'm then trying to access these files from code like this:

```
NSString *bookFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaultBooks" ofType:@"json"];
NSString *dateFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"defaultBooksDate" ofType:@"json"];
```

Obviously, I cannot see these two files listed in the '`Copy Bundle Resources`' `build phase` step, because they are generated at compile-time, so I presume that the files are simply not copied to the `.ipa` file.

Is there a step I'm missing? How can I tell `Xcode` to include the `JSON` files in the '`copy bundle resources`' step?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start using the [environment variables provided by Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html). You may as well just write the JSON directly into the output app bundle (unless you have a special reason to generate them as "source" and use Xcode to copy them, that is?  If so, see below.).

So I put such scripts into a sub-directory called `tools`, and if this script was called `generate_json.sh` then it's absolute path would be `$(PROJECT_DIR)/tools/generate_json.sh`.

Within this sctipt file you can reference the Xcode output directory (where Xcode is building the app bundle) as `$TARGET_BUILD_DIR`.

Therefore, something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat << EOF > "$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/MyApp.app/somefile.json" 

your json goes here.

EOF
```

- The alternative to this approach is to generate the `.json` file into the source tree and add it to Xcode as a proper source file and arrange for it to be copied into the app bundle in the normal manner.  This is generally only useful if it's generated from *another source file* (think `yacc` and `lex` source file).  If it changes for every build then use the approach I give here.  If it never changes then you shouldn't be doing any of this stuff anyway as you can just manually run the script outside of Xcode.